# Referring to domain name results in odd behavior from ISPConfig

Tags: debian, squirrelmail

I have a freshly set up domain and server. The server is set up with squirrelmail and ISPConfig. When I refer to the server's IP I'm taken to the `/var/www` folder, however if I refer to the domain name www.example.com I'm taken to `/var/www/example.com/web/`, which makes accessing /var/www/webmail impossible.

I'm wondering if the same error is the reason why sending mail to example.com can't be done, even though addresses in ISPConfig is set up. For instance, the address tomas@example.com is created in ISPConfig, but when I send a mail to that address I get an automated reply from www.example.com saying "user "tomas" does not exist under example.com"

I'm guessing I've done something wrong by adding the domain that hosts ISPConfig, under ISPConfig.

Could someone request additional information or shed some light on this quanandrum

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webserver is using "name based" virtual hosts, and has the DocumentRoot for the site named www.example.com set to `/var/www/example.com/web/`.  This sounds like something ISPConfig would do since it's a control panel for setting up hosted sites.

The obvious answer would be to move `/var/www/webmail` to `/var/www/example.com/web/webmail` (or to just use http://1.1.1.1/webmail/ rather than your example.com hostname).

As for the mail, there are two possibilities, either your mailserver wasn't configured by ISPConfig to use it's virtual user list, or your MX record for example.com is pointing somewhere else, so mail gets delivered there instead of to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way for doing it.

edit your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Add the following line to it.

```
Alias /webmail /usr/share/squirrelmail
```

Replace the `/usr/share/squirrelmail` with the path of your mail (I haven't tested it with a document inside /var/www).

Restart apache by

```
service apache2 restart
```

You are ready to rock.